# How to zoom the WebView in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I couldn't zoom the Webview in Xamarin.Forms. Below is the coding, can someone help me please. Thank you

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="highchart.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
    <WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <WebView.Source WebView.EnableZoomControls="true" WebView.ScalesPageToFit = "true">
            <HtmlWebViewSource x:Name="HighChart"/>
        </WebView.Source>
    </WebView>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

[This is my WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBSDc.jpg)

Comment: get rid of the ScrollView

Comment: @Jason hi, I had removed the scrollview, but still not working

Comment: Please always add correct tags for questions, this question belongs to Xamarin Forms and not Xamarin (Xamarin Native). Although, I have edited the tags and added xamarin.forms, but Xamarin Forms was nowhere metioned throughout the question by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

For Android specific (Within Shared project [FORMS])

**XAML SOLUTION:**

```
<ContentPage ...
         xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">
<WebView Source="https://www.xamarin.com"
         android:WebView.EnableZoomControls="true"
         android:WebView.DisplayZoomControls="true" />
```

**C# SOLUTION:**

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
...

            WebView.On<Android>().EnableZoomControls(true);
            WebView.On<Android>().DisplayZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I test on Android on iOS , it seems the problem only occurs on Android .

You could create a custom renderer to implement the zoom function, it works fine on my side .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))] 
namespace PDFPOC.Droid 
{ 

   public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer 
   { 
       public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) 
       {
       } 

       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e) 
       { 
           base.OnElementChanged(e); 
           if (e.NewElement != null) 
           { 
               Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true; 
               Control.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true); 
               Control.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true; 
               Control.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true; 
           } 
       } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Actually this should be accepted answer which properly addresses Xamarin Forms and solves the issue.